# how to count how many times a function has been run in javascript? and then display it on page?

Tags: javascript, function, count, console

Im working on a betting script and basically have two functions, one for if I win, and one for if I lose. I was wondering, whether any of you guys can help me with the code to be able to count how many times the function has been run,(or how many i have won, and how many times I have lost.)

I was wondering whether it would then be possible to create an element on the page which would display these?

Any help would be great. Im new to javascript and bit unsure how to make variables count??

Let me know if you need more info?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Paste in some codez or, even better, provide us with a jsfiddle/plunkr or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up two variables that equal zero, and each time there is a win/loss detected, increment the corresponding value, like so:

```
var wins = 0,
    losses = 0;

function iWin() {
    wins += 1;
}

function iLose() {
    losses += 1;
}
```

EDIT:

In order to display your wins/losses, add the following to your **html**

```
<p id="wins"></p>
<p id="losses"></p>
```

And just add two lines of code to the **JavaScript** code above:

```
var wins = 0,
    losses = 0;

function iWin() {
    wins += 1;
    document.getElementById('wins').innerHTML = wins;
}

function iLose() {
    losses += 1;
    document.getElementById('losses').innerHTML = losses;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks : ) I've now got it counting, How would i create an element to put inner html to be the variable, with it updating after each function call?